# Fetch client timezone from javascript and instantiate in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I send client's timezone using javascript,

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60
```

What is sent to SERVER is a string of sort "+5:30". Now, my question is how to instantiate corresponding TimeZone instance in Managed/server code using this Offset received from client.

Comment: That's pretty cool (+1 :), but be wary about making assumptions that the user's current browser timezone is a) correct and b) the one they wish to view times in.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime time;
var success = DateTime.TryParse("2011-07-11 11:11:11+0530", out time);
```

Basically, you can use DateTime.TryParse to parse a standardised timestamp into a proper DateTime. The TryParse will return true on success, false if there's something wrong, and the `time` variable will contain your parsed DateTime on success.

The +0530 is the timezone offset from UTC in hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom TimeZoneInfo in the following way

```
TimeZoneInfo tinfo = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("IST", TimeSpan.Parse("5:30"), "Std Time", "Display Name");
```

Then you could use something like this to convert to the destination zone

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt,tinfo)
```

I presume you were looking for something on these lines, else please edit the post further

Comment: I said the string sent to server is of sort "+5:30". But it may be any timezone depending on location of user. So, its not definite that it would be IST.

Comment: Its just an identity, you can choose your own name, since its a custom one